# Storing groups of files in Azure Blob Storage

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-blob-storage

I have groups of files using the following structure:

RandomFolderName1 [File1.jpg, File2.jpg, File3.jpg...]

RandomFolderName2 [File1.jpg, File2.jpg, File3.jpg...]

I wonder what will be the bast way to store this in Blob Storage.

Should I use GUID.jpg for every file name and manage the folder structure in the DB
Should I use FolderName+FileName.jpg, but again will have to manage the folder structure in DB
Should I use a Container for a folder and inside have File1.jpg, File2.jpg, File3.jpg...
Should I Store the whole ForderName as a zip and have all the files inside

Is there any other way to define a folder structure in Blob Storage?

**Edit**: The files will be accessed on a folder basis

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you can use file names in Azure blobs like "randomfoldername1/file1.jpg". It will look like a folder structure and some GUI clients will even let you navigate like it it. But the reality is that the "container" is the only real grouping factor and from there its just a matter of filterng the files in that container based on partial file names.

So to answer your question, you'll likely be fine putting all the files into a single container. The containers help control acces policy an each blob has its own performance target. The aside from acl reasons, the only other reason to split them across blobs in the same container is if you have enough blobs that quering them starts to degrade due to the shere number (or you're exceeding the storage account throughput targets).

You can find out more about Azure Storage abstractions and throughput targets at: http://www.windows-azure.net/windows-azure-storage-abstractions-and-their-scalability-targets/